# temporarily enable/disable ASP.NET Core request handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

is there a way to disable request handling temporarily in an ASP.NET core host?
I initialize the host at startup, but my app needs some time to be fully operational.. so while I need the host to start early (if it tries to bind to a port already in use, I want to know that as early as possible), I'd like it to idle around until my app is fully ready.

Comment: Can you provide more details. You are saying, you need to disable request handling before host starts, how is this possible. It can handle requests one host is started

Comment: as soon as I start the asp.net host, it starts processing inbound requests. I would like the whole host environment to start up, but block incoming requests until at such point that my other initialization processes area ready. So I'd call `IHost.StartAsync`, it completes, but when you make an inbound request to one of my endpoints, the request is not answered

Comment: What your are looking for is Request Pipeline Short Circuiting using conditional Middleware. I have added an answer on what I understood

Answer (score 0):

What your are looking for is **Request Pipeline Short Circuiting using conditional Middleware**.

You will have a static boolean field lets say "IsInitializing" with default value to true. Then you will have a conditional middleware app.UseWhen which will check for the value of this IsInitializing field, if its true then this middleware will short-circuit the request (you can write a string message to the output stream)

When all your bootstrapping initialization work is done, you will set IsInitializing to false. then the conditional middleware app.UseWhen will never run and your request pipeline will continue to the next middleware

Here is the sample code

**Program.cs**

```
public static bool IsInitializing { get; set; } = true;
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseWhen(ctx => Program.IsInitializing, appBuilder =>
      {
          appBuilder.Use(async (httpContext, next) => 
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Server is initilizing, please try again after sometime...")
           );
      });

    //...........................
    //--- other request pipeline configuration code
    //...........................

}
```

You will have to set `Program.IsInitialing` property to false once your initialization process is done.

Comment: That looks promising, thanks. Is there any requirement for the appBuilder.Use to write anything to the response stream? Just thinking out loud.. I'll have to get my frontend people to react to custom errors first (probably going for a 503 response when the app isn't fully initialized yet).

Comment: You can return any response, you want.